# MS Access Form from Paper Form

Tags: ms-access

I have taken over an MS Access database that was created by an employee that has moved on.  It appears that he has created a form in the database by importing a paper form that is used within our company.  What makes me believe that he imported a paper form is the exactness of Access form in relation to the paper form.

I am not sure how to ask query this using Google nor Bing.  Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this, please?  I need to do the same thing with another paper form.

Comment: It's not possible to import a paper form into Access as you describe. It's also not difficult to mock a paper form in an Access form (laying the form out to nearly exactly match a paper form) with a little effort.

Comment: He did not import a paper form. Either an image is used as a background or textboxes and labels simulate form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, June7 is right, this is a handy technique.

Scan your paper document as JPG or PNG

Create a blank Access Form, and from the Design ribbon menu, choose "Insert Image" and select your newly created JPG or PNG scan

For the image object, check the properties window and make sure the "Sizing Mode" is set to Clip (and not Stretch or Zoom)

Now re-size the Image on your form so you can see everything correctly.

Now add Text boxes on top of the image, to create fillable text fields, exactly over the same place as the ones in the scanned image behind your text boxes.

You can then make a Table with the same field names, and update the Form to use this Table as it's Data Source on the Data Tab of the Form properties.

Once you have the form working perfectly nicely,

a handy time-staving step is File -> Save Object As -> change the Form dropdown to Report

Now you have created a Report that is printable using the same data table you created earlier (and write macro or VBA code make sure you print only one record at a time if that is the normal behaviour you expect)